# Vue firebase: Cannot retrieve user data. Undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I want to retrieve user profile data to show the information in user profile page.
In the realtime database, I could insert the data as the picture below.
[image: Realtime database]

But some information such as address, business, city, phone and post, those information is undefined, so I cannot retrieve the data.

[image: My chrome dev tool.]

And this is the dev tool network tab.
[image: Network tab.]
I am using vuex, and this is my code, store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import fireApp from '@/plugins/firebase'
//import 'firebase/firebase-auth'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    user: null,
    error: null,
    busy: false,
    jobDone: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser (state, payload) {
      state.user = payload
    },
    setError (state, payload) {
      state.error = payload
    },
    clearError (state) {
      state.error = null
    },
    setBusy (state, payload) {
      state.busy = payload
    },
    setJobDone (state, payload) {
      state.jobDone = payload
    },
  },
  actions: {

    loginUser({commit}, payload) {
      commit('setBusy', true)
      commit('clearError')
      //1.login user
      //2.Find group user logins
      //3.set logged in user
      let LoggedinUser = null;
      fireApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
      .then(userCredential => {
          LoggedinUser = userCredential.user;
          var user = fireApp.auth().currentUser;
          
          const authUser = {
            id: user.uid,
            contact: user.displayName,
            business: user.business,
            email: user.email,
            phone: user.phone,
            address: user.address,
            post: user.post,
            city: user.city,
          }

          return fireApp.database().ref('groups').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Pro').once('value')
          .then(snapShot => {
            const groupKey = Object.keys(snapShot.val())[0]
            return fireApp.database().ref(`userGroups/${groupKey}`).child(`${authUser.id}`).once('value')
              .then(ugroupSnap => {
                if (ugroupSnap.exists()) {
                  authUser.role = 'pro'
                }
                
                console.log('USER', authUser)
                commit('setUser', authUser)
                commit('setBusy', false)
                commit('setJobDone', true)
              })
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          commit('setBusy', false)
          commit('setError', error)
      })
  },


},
  getters: {
    user (state) {
      return state.user
    },
    loginStatusPro (state) {
      return state.user !== null && state.user !== undefined
    },
    userRole (state) {
      const isLoggedIn = state.user !== null && state.user !== undefined
      return(isLoggedIn) ? state.user.role : 'Pro'
    },
    error (state) {
      return state.error
    },
    busy (state) {
        return state.busy
    },
    jobDone (state) {
        return state.jobDone
    }
  },
  modules: {
    
  
  }
})
```

This is user profile page. Profile.vue

```
<script>
import ErrorBar from '@/components/ErrorBar'
import apiJobMixin from '@/mixins/apiJobMixin'
    export default {
        data() {
        return {
            //contact: "",
            business: "",
            address: "",
            post: "",
            city: "",
        }
        },
        mixins: [apiJobMixin],
        components: {
            ErrorBar: ErrorBar
        },
        created () {
            this.$store.commit('clearError')
            const user = this.$store.getters.user
            if (user) {
                //this.contact = user.contact
                this.business = user.business
                this.address = user.address
                this.post = user.post
                this.city = user.city
            }
        }, 
        computed: {      
            userData () {
                return this.$store.getters.user
            }
        },
        watch: {      
            userData (value) {
                if (value) {
                    //this.contact = value.contact
                    this.business = value.business
                    this.address = value.address
                    this.post = value.post
                    this.city = value.city
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: so storing in the DB works, retrieving doesn't ... sounds like a **server side** problem ... client side code won't help

Comment: But I could retrieve uid, contact(displayName), email, password, and role. Is this issue still server side problem? Or should I show firebase rule?

Comment: You say the data is in the DB ... can you confirm that when you request the data it comes to the client? browser developer tools network tab, check the response for the request

Comment: I checked now, and I couldn't get information, the status is failed or canceled. I will upload the picture. But I could access to the user id.

Comment: I restarted the server, then no error comes up.

Comment: oh .. what does that have to do with checking if the data is actually being sent by the server? I can't check it for you ... you need to determine where the "loss" is happening, database, web server or client